# merge two thresholds for two 3D arrays into a list

Tags: numpy

I have the first 3D array of size (50,250,250) that includes data points (1,2,3,4,5). I set up a threshold that is 3, where the data points above should equal to 1 and below it equal to 0. the only exception is when the data points are equal to 3, it has to test the second threshold (threshold1=50) that is based on the second 3D array of size (50,250,250). my equation is how to include the two thresholds in my code! In other words, the for loop will check every datapoint in array 1 and perform the first threshold testing, if the datapoint is equal to 3, the for loop should check the counterpart of that datapoint in the second array for the second threshold testing! I have tried the below code, but the results did not make sense

```
res1=[]
f1=numpy.ones((250, 250))
threshold=3
threshold1=30

for i in array1:
        i = i.data
        ii= f1*i
        ii[ii < threshold]  = 0
        ii[ii > threshold]  = 1
        res1.append(ii)
        if ii[ii == threshold]:
            for j in array2:
                j = j.data
                jj[jj < threshold1]  = 0
                jj[jj > threshold1]  = 1
                res1.append(jj)
```

---

```
Array1:
   array([[[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        ...,
        [3., 3., 3., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [3., 3., 3., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [3., 3., 3., ..., 0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        ...,
        [3., 3., 3., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [3., 3., 3., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [3., 3., 3., ..., 0., 0., 0.]],
```

---

```
    Array2:[[        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,         nan,
       0.9839769,   1.7042577],
    [        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,         nan,
             nan,         nan],
    [        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,   3.2351596,
       2.0924768,   1.7604152],
    ...,
    [        nan,         nan,         nan, ..., 158.48865  ,
     158.48865  , 125.888    ],
    [        nan,         nan,         nan, ..., 158.48865  ,
     158.48865  , 158.48865  ],
    [        nan,         nan,         nan, ..., 125.88556  ,
     158.48865  , 158.48865  ]],
```

---

the produced list (rest1)

```
`[array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        ...,
        [1., 1., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.]]),
 array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        ...,
        [1., 1., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.]]),
 array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],`
```

Comment: May I ask what is your array1 and array2? Because if it's your 3D array, the f1 and the 2D arrays in the 3D array do not have the same size.

Comment: I updated the post! You are right, the 2D and 3D  arrays have to be the same size which is (250,250)

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew thank you for the reply! I updated the post adding more info! so the created list ( res1) should take in consideration the two arrays

Comment: May I ask what is your expected output after doing this? Because I'm quite confuse with what you are trying to perform on the second if condition. And is every 2D array in your array1 has at least a 3 in it?

Comment: so I trying to produce a list (res1)  size (50) and each element is a 2D array (250,250). The list will check array1 for threshold =3, and then check array 2 for threshold1=30. the produced list will have numbers 1 and 0 that are based on the thresholds testing

Comment: It is worth mentioning that I convert the two 3D arrays to lists that have a size of the produced list (size of 50 where each element is 2D array size (250,250)). so that I can perform the for loop

Comment: let me explain it more! the for loop will check every datapoint in array 1 and perform the first threshold testing, if the datapoint is equal to 3, the for loop should check counterpart of that datapoint in the second array for the second  threshold testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, for your second if condition, you are trying to see whether there is at least a 3 value in that array1, and then you will choose that 2D array of the same position. In that case, you should use `in` operator.

```
for i in range(len(array1)):
    if threshold in array1[i]:
        array2[i][array2[i] < threshold1]  = 0
        array2[i][array2[i] > threshold1]  = 1
        res1.append(array2[i])
    else:    
        array1[i][array1[i] < threshold]  = 0
        array1[i][array1[i] > threshold]  = 1
        res1.append(array1[i])
```

The above method is a bit lengthy for numpy. There's a numpy way to do this, too.

```
array1[array1 < threshold] = 0
array1[array1 > threshold] = 1

array2_condition = np.unique(np.argwhere(array1 == 3)[:,0]) # return the index of array1 if 3 in array1
chosen_array2 = array2[array2_condition]
chosen_array2[chosen_array2 < threshold1] = 0
chosen_array2[chosen_array2 > threshold1] = 1

array2[array2_condition] = chosen_array2 # if you still want array2 values to be changed

res1 = array1
res1[array2_condition] = chosen_array2  # Final result
```

### Update

As was mentioned by the OP, every 2D array has at least a 3 in it. So, the `array2_condition` is not applicable. Instead, we will modify the `array2_condition` and use a for loop to change the elements.

```
res1 = array1
res1[res1 < threshold] = 0
res1[res1 > threshold] = 1

array2_condition = np.argwhere(array1 == 3)

for data in array2_condition:
    if array2[tuple(data)] > threshold1:
        res1[tuple(data)] = 1
    elif array2[tuple(data)] < threshold1:
        res12[tuple(data)] = 0
```

Comment: I tested your code, and the results still are not logical, as the produced list gave either nan or o values, where it should give 1 value in some cases

Comment: Which array gives you nan values? Also, may I ask if you have 3 in all the 50 2D-arrays?

Comment: the produced array (res1)! it is okay it gave nan as the second array has nan, but the issue is that there is not any 1 where it should return 1 in some cases

Comment: Yes, I have a 3 value in the first array (array1). the 3 value occurs in array 1, and once it appears, we should check the threshold1 in array 2

Comment: Try this, see if it works for you. The updated code only focuses on getting the `res1`, not changing the `array1` and `array2`

Comment: Thank you so much @kevin Choon Liang Yew, the updated code worked great, the only thing is that the values of the produced list (res1) are 0,1  and 2, but it should give 0 and 1 values

Comment: I was trying to navigate through the updated code, I could not find why values of 2 are produced

Comment: Also, I noticed that  I need to re-read array1 every time I run this code because the array1 took the value of ret1 for the first run and resulting res1 will be all 0 values for the second run

Comment: I found out that the 2 values produced due to nan values in array2, so I added the else to if condition

Comment: For the first line of updated code, if you want the array1 and 2 to change as well, you can look through the previous codes before you assign it to the `res1`. If it works for you, please mark this solution as correct. Thank you

Comment: the updated code worked and the problem is solved! thank you so much